# php, regex and ldifde base64_encode / Replace multiple lines

Tags: php, regex

I need a simple regex string from you.

**For example, thats my regex example.**

```
preg_replace('#([a-z]+)\:\:' . "([\r\n a-z0-9=]*)" . '#is', '\1:: \2', /* Example string */)
```

**And thats the example string.**

```
dn: CN=Gast,CN=Users,DC=question,DC=local
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
cn: Gast
description:: 
 Vm9yZGVmaW5pZXJ0ZXMgS29udG8gZsO8ciBHYXN0enVncmlmZiBhdWYgZGVuIENvbXB1dGVyIGJ6dy
 4gZGllIERvbcOkbmU=
name: Gast
sAMAccountName: Gast
unicodePwd::IgA2AEcATQBNAHQANwBoADcAIgA=
userAccountControl:512
```

**The result is the following.**

```
dn: CN=Gast,CN=Users,DC=question,DC=local
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
cn: Gast
description:  
 Vm9yZGVmaW5pZXJ0ZXMgS29udG8gZsO8ciBHYXN0enVncmlmZiBhdWYgZGVuIENvbXB1dGVyIGJ6dy
 4gZGllIERvbcOkbmU=
name: Gast
sAMAccountName: Gast
unicodePwd::IgA2AEcATQBNAHQANwBoADcAIgA=
userAccountControl:512
```

**I would have this result.**

```
dn: CN=Gast,CN=Users,DC=question,DC=local
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
cn: Gast
description:: Vm9yZGVmaW5pZXJ0ZXMgS29udG8gZsO8ciBHYXN0enVncmlmZiBhdWYgZGVuIENvbXB1dGVyIGJ6dy4gZGllIERvbcOkbmU=
name: Gast
sAMAccountName: Gast
unicodePwd::IgA2AEcATQBNAHQANwBoADcAIgA=
userAccountControl:512
```

**Then i could do this.**

```
$lines = explode("\r\n", /* Example string */);
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $tmp = explode(':', $line);
    if(count($tmp) > 2)
    {
        $tmp = explode('::', $line);
        $tmp[1] = base64_decode($tmp[1]);
    }
}
```

Or is it possible to do this easier??

**Thank you in Advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also this would be possible:

1.) Strip spaces after `::` and space-newlines-space

```
$str = preg_replace('/::\K\s+|\s*\n(?=[^:]*(\n|$))\s*/', "", $str);
```

Regex [explanation at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/rB6aD8/1). Strips white-space characters after `::` | OR space-newlines-space if no colon exists in the next line (checking with a [lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)).

2.) base64 decode [using a callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=::)\S+/',
       function ($m) { return base64_decode($m[0]); },
       $str);
```

`\S+` Non-white-space characters after a `::` using a [lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html), [see regex101](http://regex101.com/r/gD1iN9/1)

3.) Add space after `::`

```
$str = str_replace("::", ":: ", $str);
```

See [example at eval.in](https://eval.in/179633)

---

If your PHP version has no support for anonymous functions, swap the function out:

```
function b64d ($m) { return base64_decode($m[0]); }
$str = preg_replace_callback('~(?<=::)\S+~', "b64d", $str);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes really good!! Thank you. I dont know why i'm not using multiple things like yours. But i dont now for what \K stands and why you use \n and not \r\n ^^

Comment: @PatrickB Used `\K` as a lookbehind here, same as `(?<=::)\s+|...`. [Read more about \K](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#k). And to other question: I used only `\n` because it's preceded by `\s*` whitch is a shorthand for `[ \t\r\n\f]` (including `\r`) and makes it more compatible. Strip spaces with at least one `\n` newline if not followed by any amount of `non-colons` and another `\n` or end. Happy answer works for you :)